# Quotient of Unit Quaternions by Subgoup (Lie Groups)

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G \leq Sp(1)\cong S^3$ (unit quaternions) be a discrete subgroup of order 120 (the Binary Icosahedral Group, not the other one), with presentation $G=<s,t| s^2=t^3=(st)^5>$. $\hspace{2mm}G$ is a perfect group with one non-trivial normal subgroup of order $2$ (its center).

$a.)$ Show that $M=Sp(1)/G$ is a compact, oriented manifold without boundary, and that it has the same integral homology groups as $S^3$.

$b.)$ Let $X$ be the CW-complex formed by attaching two $2-$cells to $M$, using loops representing $s$ and $t$ as the attaching maps. Compute $H_*(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

$\space$

For $a.)$, since $S^3$ is compact and $M$ is its image under the projection map $M$ must also be compact. Since this is a covering projection, $M$ is locally just like $S^3$ and therefore a manifold w/o boundary.

For orientability, I'm thinking since $\pi_1(M)=G$, if $M$ is not orientable then it has a double cover, which implies a subgroup of $\pi_1(M)=G$ of index two (which is normal), but this does not exist, so $M$ must be orientable. Is $M$ a Lie group? (if $G$ is normal I know that it is)

$b.$ I'm not sure.

Comment: Try using the standard tricks - Poincare duality, excision, cofibration sequence ...

Comment: Yeah, for part (a), assuming what I have written is correct, I see how it follows from duality. I know that $G$ can be realized as $\pi_1$ of some 2 dim CW complex, but I'm guessing I can't use that for part (b) really. Although I see that $H_1=H_0=0$. Think $H_3$ stays $\mathbb{Z}$, not sure about $H_2$. BTW not to familiar w/ cofibration sequences

Comment: Every group is the fundamental group of some 2 dim CW complex, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the group G acts on the sphere by orientation preserving diffeo without fixed points, the quotient is an orientable manifold of dimension three, obviously compact. In particular, H_3 is Z The map from the sphere to M is clearly the universal covering space of M, so the fundamental group of M is G. One can check That G is perfecto, so that H_1  is zero. Poincaré duality then implies that H_2 is also zero.

Comment: Thanks, how do we know these diffeomorphisms are orientation preserving though?

Comment: They are translations in a connected Lie groups.